# JUnit 5 tests not detected when TestContainers dependencies exist in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, junit5, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

1. I have a maven project the uses both TestContainers (latest 1.5.2) and JUnit 5 (5.7.0) tests. Surefire plugin set to version 2.22.2 (see full POM below). Maven version is 3.6.0 and using Java 11.
2. I created two test classes: one uses JUnit 4.12 (available through TestContainers dependencies) and the other uses JUnit 5.7.0
3. When the TestContainers dependencies in POM are defined, a call to `mvn test` only detects the JUnit 4.12 tests
4. When the TestContainers dependencies in POM are commented out, a call to `mvn test` detects both JUnit 4.12 and JUnit 5.7.0 tests
5. adding an `exclusion` to the TestContainers dependency to exclude JUnit 4.12 allows maven to detect and run JUnit 5 tests, BUT it throws an exception from any call to TestContainers API: `class file for org.junit.rules.TestRule not found`

**POM.XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-mvn-containers-junit-collision</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Example JUnit5 test with a call to TestContainers API:**

When excluding `Junit 4` from TestContainer dependency, JUnit5 tests are detected, but adding a call to any TestContainers API results in a compilation error:

```
@Testcontainers
public class TesterJunit570 {

    @Container
    private static final GenericContainer<?> redis = new GenericContainer<>("redis:alpine")
            .withExposedPorts(6379); // this causes the compilation error below

    @Test
    public void test1(){   // this JUnit 5 test is detected when Junit 4 is excluded from TestContainers POM dependencies
        System.out.println("Test JUnit 5");
    }
}
```

Compilation error details:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project test-mvn-containers-junit-collision: Compilation failure
[ERROR] [...]/src/test/java/events/TesterJunit570.java:[13,13] cannot access org.junit.rules.TestRule
[ERROR]   class file for org.junit.rules.TestRule not found
```

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE:

Managed to bypass this issue by using version surefire plugin version `3.0.0-M5` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62552652/run-both-junit-4-and-junit5-with-maven-surefire-plugin-2020):

> We have improved the plugin in the 3.0.0-M5 version so that you do not need to use engines in your dependencies. This new approach avoids using internal code of the engine in your tests and it enables you to only call the API