# cannot access org.junit.rules.TestRule withUser("testcontainers") (an integration test for ActiveMQ Artemis)

Tags: spring-boot, junit4, junit5, activemq-artemis, spring-boot-testcontainers

I have an old project that needed to be connected to ActiveMQ Artemis. Then I decided to write an integration test. However, I get an error at startup.

I use Spring 2.5.14 and `build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply from: 'confluence.gradle'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
....
dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis'

    implementation "org.messaginghub:pooled-jms:$jmsPoolConnectionVersion"
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

.....
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:activemq:1.19.5"
    testImplementation 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-junit-5:2.32.0'

    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.19.5'


}
```

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class ContainerConfig {


    ArtemisContainer artemis = new ArtemisContainer("apache/activemq-artemis:2.30.0-alpine")
            .withUser("testcontainers")
            .withPassword("testcontainers");



    @Test
    public void test(){
        
        Assertions.assertTrue(true);
    }
```

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ContainerConfig {

    public static final GenericContainer<?> artemisContainer;

    static {

        DockerImageName postgres = DockerImageName.parse("apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpine");

        artemisContainer = new GenericContainer<>(
                DockerImageName.parse("apache/activemq-artemis:latest-alpine"))
                .withEnv("ANONYMOUS_LOGIN", "true")
                .withExposedPorts(61616);

        artemisContainer.start();
    }
```

However, this error occurs:

```
error: cannot access org.junit.rules.TestRule
          .withUser("testcontainers")
          ^
class file for org.junit.rules.TestRule not found
```

```
 org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test -> 2.5.14
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.5.14 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.5.14
|    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.5.14 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.5.14

......
 +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2
|    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2
|    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2 (c)
|    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2 (c)
|    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2 (c)
|    |    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.2 (c)
|    |    |    +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.2 (c)
|    |    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.7.2 (c)
|    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2
|    |    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
|    |    |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
|    |    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.7.2
|    |    |         +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2 (*)
|    |    |         \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
|    |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.7.2
|    |    |    +--- org.junit:junit-bom:5.7.2 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
|    |    |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.2 (*)
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I've tried the tips listed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62552652/run-both-junit-4-and-junit5-with-maven-surefire-plugin-2020 and it didn't help.

Comment: You are using JUnit5 **not** JUnit4. The `@ExtendWith` is for JUnit5. So you are mixing to versions of junit which won't work.

Comment: So I  also used it without junit 4, the error is the same

Comment: Removing JUnit 4 as a dependency won't change a thing, the problem is that your tests are a mix, use 1 or the other not both in a single test. Make sure your `@Test` is the JUnit5 version and not the JUnit4 version).

Comment: I can't use spring boot 3.x. Everything works for me on Spring boot 3.x. I need to make changes to the old project, and there is Spring boot 2.5.x and junit5. But thanks. I'll try to use it.

Comment: I deleted the property : exclude group: 'junit'. There is no mistake anymore